# How to set InnerHtml to tablecell in DataGrid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datagrid, textbox

I have created a dynamic datagrid and the cell are textboxes so the cells can be edited directly from the grid.

But when I try print there is an issue with Chrome that is doesn't show the textboxes so all my cells are blank.

It works if I set the cell to `c.Text = li.InnerHtml` but then I lose the textbox. How can I set the InnerHtml and still keep the textbox in the cell?

```
foreach (TableCell c in e.Item.Cells)
{
    if ((Headers[count].ToUpper().Equals("BUY0_45")) && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Pager && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer && !beendone)
    {
          HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
          li.InnerHtml = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["Buy0_45"].ToString();
          //c.Text = li.InnerHtml;
          c.Text = "<input id=\"txtBuy0-45" + ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["ID"].ToString() + "\" style=\"width:50px\" type=\"text\" value=\"" + ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["Buy0_45"].ToString() + "\" onblur=\"UpdateBuyRate('0'," +  ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["ID"].ToString() + ",this.value)\" />";
    } 
}
```

HTML markup: `<input id="txtBuy0-456" style="width:50px" type="text" value="5.0000" onblur="UpdateBuyRate('0',6,this.value)">`

Comment: Do you have a separate stylesheet for print media? Your text boxes should print their contents.

Comment: You need to concatenate maybe? `c.Text += "<input id=\...`?

Comment: @hardkoded doing that just displays the value twice in the cell. The value inside the textbox and the value again outside the textbox

Comment: @Crowcoder This is an issue with Chrome that it doesn't show textboxes when trying to print

Comment: @user123456789 except, they show for me when I print.

Comment: @Crowcoder no I don't have a separate stylesheet for print media. What do I need to do to get the text boxes to print?

Comment: I'd tell you if I knew, all I can do is guess. Maybe try adding an actual TextBox control to the TableCell's Control collection?

Comment: @Crowcoder I have tried that, still the same issue of the cell showing as blank when I try print

Comment: Can you do an "Inspect" on one of the table rows and add the html it is creating to the question?

Comment: @Crowcoder ok I tried that and tried to print again but the cell is still blank on the printout

Comment: Tried what? I meant post the html markup in the question so we can see what is generated.

Comment: @Crowcoder sorry misunderstood what you wanted. Question is updated now.

Comment: can you show the enclosing row also?